# Man keeps seeing his dead wife as she was still living with him

Tags: identify-this-movie

I think the movie is Japanese, although I'm not completely sure. It's certainly Asian, though, and it takes place in a city. The movie was made during the 90s or 2000s.

The main character (a man, ~40 years old) cannot bear the loss of his wife and keeps seeing her like she was still living with him.

I remember two scenes from the movie. In the first scene the man is having dinner with his friends (another couple) and he orders food for his wife, who's sitting next to him -- but in reality it's just an empty seat. In the second scene the man and his wife are riding a motorbike in a big city.

It it not *Visitor Q*, *Rampo Noir*, *Three (3 Extremes II)*, *Departures*, *Be With You*, *Cherry Blossoms*, *Audition*, or *Nang Nak*.

Comment: @Meat Trademark: I am the one who asked the question. Since I come here only as a guest without an account, I can't edit the original post (neither can I "add coment"). Perhaps [this forum topic](http://www.askmehelpdesk.com/movies/man-his-imaginary-non-existent-deceased-wife-783363.html#post3615996) will verify that I am the same person, therefore I consider it perfectly fine to use a declarative statement.

Comment: The only thing I can say in my defense is it was flagged for review (because of length) and I failed to open the whole question. Seeing the answer out of context looked shady not knowing it was the same person. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

Solved: it is [San Taam AKA Mad Detective](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0969269/).

Thanks to [this site](http://050actionexpress.blogspot.cz/2011/09/mad-detectivesun-taam-2007.html), which contains the keyword "imaginary wife".

Comment: Oops. Egg on face.